# How do I call my function on Onsen carousel change?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

```html
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen 
              auto-scroll-ratio="0.2" var="carousel" style="position:initial" 
              on-carousel-change="selected($index)">            
</ons-carousel>
```

how can I call my function?

Comment: I have fixed the duplicated code snippet and made it more readable, but the question is still lacking clear explanation of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`ons-carousel` fires a [`postchange` event](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#event-postchange) every time it changes. You can listen for it and run your function.

If you use AngularJS with Onsen UI (I guess you do since you have `var` attribute), you can specify a handler for this event directly with [`ons-postchange` attribute](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#attributes): `ons-postchange="myHandler($event, myData)"`.

Comment: Hey!  We answered at the same time!  Great job on beta 7!!

Comment: <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen auto-scroll-ratio="0.2" var="carousel" style="position:initial;background:#ccc;height:260px" ons-postchange="on('postchange', callalert())">   Still it is not working

Comment: @AniketDhole Just do `ons-postchange="callalert()"`.

Comment: @Munsterlander Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS, Onsen only supports this event model: `ons-postchange`.  `on-carousel-change` is not a valid event and as such is not supported by `ons-carousel`.

Working examples and explanations are posted here:

Onsen 1.x - https://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html

Onsen 2 - https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-carousel.html